# Will Ubuntu be able to replace windows 7 on my pc? And if which version will work for me?

Tags: boot

I have a low spec pc.It has 1 gigabyte RAM, 2.8 ghz Intel processor, 256 mb graphics card. CurrentIy I'm running Windows 7.I heard that Ubuntu is way faster than windows 7. I just do the basics in computer like watching videos, listening songs and surfing web. So should I use Ubuntu instead of windows 7 or stick to windows only. And if Ubuntu is better for me than which version should I use. Thanks.
Please reply!!!!

Comment: Even if [general consensus](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/350004) is that 1 GB RAM is enough, the first thing I would do is to add more RAM. Go up to 2 GB or better 4 GB if the PC support it. You can even find used RAM module that will do the job in some shop if you budget is tiny. Ubuntu will not transform your Ford T into a Ferrari 488.

Comment: Try Lubuntu, we've had good luck on similar hardware.

Comment: Or try Xubuntu. It looks better and is more versatile (my opinion!) and is almost as lightweight as Lubuntu. Just make sure you chose a 32bit version! And you should either take version 15.04 (newest, but will have to be upgraded in a few months) or 14.04 LTS (about a year old, but supported for 4 more years, no soon upgrade needed)

Answer (score 2):

While as @solsTiCe's comment that installing Linux or specifically Ubuntu won't give your PC more resources is true, it will however make more efficient use of those resources.
If you wish to continue using your PC without upgrading hardware - then that is entirely possible with Ubuntu. It will even arguably work faster than with Windows as your hardware configuration is [barely the minimum Win7 supports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7#System_requirements), while it is roughly [twice of Ubuntu's minimum requirement](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).
If you do decide to switch to Ubuntu then here are a few pointers that might help you out further:

- First of all [test Ubuntu as a Live system](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install), see whether you like it.
- If you like it then I'd recommend using a window manager that's easy on resources.
  While they might not look as "good" as other more heavier window managers they do make a fine job out of conserving memory (both on your graphics card and RAM). Either [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) might be good.
   (Or just `apt-get install` one you like after you installed your base system.)